# Unknown system error -8 when running yarn dev command

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a dev script that looks like this.

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "./test.sh",
},
```

When trying to run 'yarn dev' command. I get the following error:

```
Internal Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at N1 (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:4:6994)
    at ch.implementation (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:392:17803)
    at ch.exec (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:395:1585)
    at ch.run (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:395:1756)
    at c9 (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:401:6449)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async LRe (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:403:16)
    at async o (/Users/p/Desktop/project/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.4.cjs:403:146)
```

This error occurs regardless of what is inside 'test.sh'. I have tried just writing 'Hello World' in there yet the error persist.

Has anyone seen this error?

I have tried reinstalling node, brew, yarn, VS, nvm etc. That did not solve my issue.

Note, this is a new macbook. I have tried changing permissions without success aswell.

Comment: Please include code for tesh.sh and package.json files. What version of node are you using?

Comment: I am also seeing this issue.  In my case I have NodeJS 18.15.0 and yarn 3.5.0.  Interestingly enough things work on NodeJS 14.18.1.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue as well.

I had a script that was being called from a Node.JS application. The script had the proper permissions but lacked a specific interpreter. It worked fine when invoked from the shell but failed when Node called it.

The solution was to add the interpreter to the script at the top of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
... REST OF FILE
```

Comment: This solved my problem too.